# Create a properties file with version numbers of each dependent component

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am working on a fairly big project structure which we recently migrated to maven. The structure is currently as follows:

Parent-Project

- shared
- core (dependency: "shared")
- webservice (dependency: "shared", "core")
- webapp (dependency: "shared")
- tools

  - gui client (dependency: "shared")
  - reporting client (dependency: "shared")
  - monitoring client (dependency: "shared", "core")
  - ...

Every component has it's own project version. How can I automatically create a `version.properties` file for each build artifact? The properties file needs to contain all version numbers of all components included in the package.

Desired output for component webservice:

```
webservice.version=1.0-SNAPSHOT
shared.version=0.9
core.version=1.1
```

Desired output for component webapp:

```
webapp.version=1.1
shared.version=0.9
```

I know about resource filtering, but I couldn't manage how to include the versions of every dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency:list plugin will get you something close.  You can set it up as:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>create-versions-file</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>list</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <includeGroupIds>org.yourgroup1,org.yourgroup2</includeGroupIds>
    <outputScope>false</outputScope>
    <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/versions.info</outputFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The resulting output would be:

```
The following files have been resolved:
  org.yourgroup1:webservice:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  org.yourgroup1:shared:jar:0.9
  org.yourgroup2:core:jar:1.1
```

Now obviously this is not exactly what you wanted.  To get the exact format you wanted you can either create your own plugin (preferably starting from the source for the dependency list mojo) or use the maven-replacer-plugin to munge the above output file into the format you want.

Comment: That sounds like a good start for me. I'll give that a try. Thanks.